# MVVM - NullReferenceException when set ControlTemplate that has DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatemplate

In one of my views I have a ContentControl bound to a DataTemplate defined as resource in the same page. Inside it, I have a control filled at runtime with different controlTemplates (four) by setting the bound property declared in the triggers of the dataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DeviceSetupDataTemplate">
        <Control x:Name="theControl" Template="{DynamicResource BanknotesReaderControlTemplate}" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceSetup.ShowBanknotesReaderControlTemplate, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Value="true" >
                <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource BanknotesReaderControlTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceSetup.ShowCoinsReaderControlTemplate, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Value="true" >
                <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource CoinsReaderControlTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceSetup.ShowHoppersControlTemplate, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Value="true" >
                <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource HoppersControlTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceSetup.ShowCoinsCashBoxControlTemplate, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Value="true" >
                <Setter TargetName="theControl" Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource CoinsCashBoxControlTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

... and the content control inside my Grid:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource DeviceSetupDataTemplate}" Margin="5" />
```

In two of my ControlTemplates I have a DataGrid, bounded to List of my custom object (here there's one of them):

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BanknotesReaderControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Grid d:DesignWidth="772.02" d:DesignHeight="532.76" Margin="15,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.08*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.08*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.44*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Button Margin="0,3,10,3" Command="{Binding DeviceSetup.AddBanknoteType, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Content="{DynamicResource 442}" Width="85" Style="{DynamicResource DeviceSetupButtonStyle}" Height="Auto" Padding="2,1" />
                <Button Margin="0,3,10,3" Command="{Binding DeviceSetup.ChangeBanknoteType, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Content="{DynamicResource 444}" Width="85" Style="{DynamicResource DeviceSetupButtonStyle}" Padding="2,1" />
                <Button Margin="0,3" Command="{Binding DeviceSetup.DeleteBanknoteType, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Content="{DynamicResource 443}" Width="85" Style="{DynamicResource DeviceSetupButtonStyle}" Height="Auto" Padding="2,1" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,5" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceSetup.BanknotesDetails, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" SelectedItem="{Binding DeviceSetup.SelectedBanknoteDetails, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Width="5*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="{DynamicResource 445}" Width="20*" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource SmallSizedTextBlockBlackPlusMatic}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Currency}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="{DynamicResource 446}" Width="25*" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource SmallSizedTextBlockBlackPlusMatic}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MoneyCode}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="{DynamicResource 447}" Width="50*" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource SmallSizedTextBlockBlackPlusMatic}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>    
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>    
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And now the problem: On the view I have four buttons connected to viewModel by commands and inside it the callBack where I change the bool value of the property to change the control templates.
Sometimes, seems randomly, I got a NullReferenceException when I set to true the boolean property in order to display the controltemplate that has Inside the datagrid.
MoreOver, inside the stacktrace of the exception, I found a reference to DataGridCellItemAutomationPeer... I think this can be a good starting point to investigate, but sincerely I don't know how to do.

Thank you in advace..

Comment: I found right now that the problem occur systematically if I select a row of the datagrid when I change control template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND!!

I really don't explain why, but if I set the IsEnabled property of the DataGrid to false BEFORE to change the DataTemplate I don't get any exceptions.

So I simply put a binding to IsEnabled of the datagrid and just before to change to a different ControlTemplate I set the property to false, then to true at the end of the callback of the command.

L.